# Cannot install tensorflow:

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

trying to install tensorflow with conda but this error shows up when i try to pip install it:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\myusername\.conda\envs\tf\python.exe "C:\Users\myusername\.conda\envs\tf\Scripts\pip-script.py" install tensorflow'
```

can anyone help?

Comment: What command are you trying to use to install?

Comment: pip install tensorflow

Comment: Are you in a Conda environment coz I see a `.conda` in your path? If yes, then try `conda create -n tf tensorflow` and then `conda activate tf`

Comment: You can create tensorflow using python 3.8 as `conda create --name tf python=3.8;
conda activate tf ; pip install tensorflow; import tensorflow`. It should work. Thanks!